# How to decorate Laravel Eloquent information in the jQuery tooltip?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I want to decorate Eloquent information on the tooltip. So in this code, one 'Event' can have many 'Participant'. And They are connected eloquently. So I can show the 'date', 'name' in the below code. 
But the problem is I want to decorate it using HTML or with other attributes in tooltip(); function.

I tried to call it from public/foojquery.js, but i think it's out of MVC pattern. In other way, I try to define `$event->participants->pluck('date', 'name)` in the model and call it, somehow it fails.

**php**

```
public function index(): View
{
        $detail = Event::with('participants')->get();
        return view('events.index', compact('detail'));
}
```

**Javascript**

```
 function showTooltips(self){ // I cannot call the eloquent here.
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
            content: function(){
                return $(this).prop('title');
            track: true
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
// View file

    <tbody id="EL">
        @foreach($detail as $event)
<td><a href="{{ route('participants.create', $event->id) }}"
    data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="
        {{ $event->participants->pluck('date', 'name') }}<br>
    "> {{ $event->title }} </a></td>
```

**What tooltip shows:**

```
{"participant1":"2019-03-02","participant2":"2019-03-04"}
```

**What I want to do** :

```
 1. participant1: 2019-03-02 
 2. participant2: 2019-03-04
```

+this code also not working ;( (tooltip ain't showed up)

```
<td class="td"><a href="{{ route('participants.create', $event->id) }}"
                    data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-container="body" data-content="
                    <ul>
                    @foreach ($datas as $key => $value)
                      <li>{{$key}} : {{$value}}</li>
                    @endforeach
                    </ul>
                        {{-- {{ $event->participants->pluck('date', 'name') }}<br> --}}
                    "> {{ $event->title }} </a></td>
```

Comment: if you said that an event can have many participants, base on your premise, then you should join all participants first in a form of string, then output it in the view (i assume pluck returns an array still, so just implode it with newline)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `data-content` for adding html content in tooltip.

```
@php
   $datas = $event->participants->pluck('date', 'name');
@endphp
<a href="{{ route('participants.create', $event->id) }}"
data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-container="body" data-content="
    <ul>
    @foreach ($datas as $data)
      <li>{{$data->name}} : {{$data->date}}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
"> {{ $event->title }} </a>
```

in your script you only want to initialize the tooltip..
try this code

Comment: I tried yours and There's error that 'Trying to get property 'name' of non-object'. So I tried like $data['name'], neither works ;(
If I dd($datas), it shows
`Collection {#242 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "I'm a participant!" => "2019-08-30"
    "klj22" => "2019-09-02"
  ]
}`

Comment: try dd($data) inside foreach loop

Comment: it's in foreach loop! 
`<tbody id="EL"> @foreach($detail as $event)
            @php
            $datas = $event->participants->pluck('date', 'name');
            // dd($datas);
            @endphp`
in the @foreach loop you wrote for me, dd ain't works. ; (